# Kotlin Android - Copy to Clipboard from Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, kotlin, clipboard

I need to copy a text to clipboard, so I used a code that I already used in MainActivity:

```
 val myClipboard: ClipboardManager = getSystemService(CLIPBOARD_SERVICE) as ClipboardManager
 val myClip: ClipData
```

The problem is, this code works fine on an Activity but don't (obviously) on a Fragment.

on `getSystemService`:

> Type inference failed: fun  getSystemService(p0: Context, p1: Class): T?
>   cannot be applied to
>   (String)

on `CLIPBOARD_SERVICE`:

> Type mismatch: inferred type is String but Context was expected

I've tried with

`getSystemService(context!!, CLIPBOARD_SERVICE)`

but doesn't works

Answer (score 11, accepted):

When your class is a fragment you can get a reference to its parent Activity by calling `getActivity()` in Java or just `activity` in Kotlin.

Using this approach you can change the code in your Activity to

```
val myClipboard: ClipboardManager = activity.getSystemService(CLIPBOARD_SERVICE) as ClipboardManager
val myClip: ClipData
```

Answer (score 11):

It's not a good idea to use force unwrap(!!) on context in Kotlin.
In your fragment class you can use below code which is safe for any NPE and very clean.

```
(requireActivity().getSystemService(CLIPBOARD_SERVICE) as ClipboardManager).apply {
        setPrimaryClip(ClipData.newPlainText("simple text", "some other text"))
    }
```

Happy Coding!

Comment: As of today, this is the appropriate answer

Answer (score 4):

In android x the constructor of `getSystemService()` changes.. Now u have to call to clipboard like this(You can Use `activity!!` or  `context!!`)

```
var myClipboard = getSystemService(context!!, ClipboardManager::class.java) as ClipboardManager
val clip: ClipData = ClipData.newPlainText("simple text", text)

myClipboard.setPrimaryClip(clip)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a neat extension fun for Kotlin users:

```kotlin
fun Fragment.copyToClipboard(text: String, label: String? = null) {
    (requireActivity().getSystemService(CLIPBOARD_SERVICE) as ClipboardManager).apply {
        setPrimaryClip(ClipData.newPlainText(null, text))
    }
    displayToast(R.string.text_copied_to_clipboard, Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
}
```